# Apache won't start

Tags: apache-httpd, configuration, session, php5

I'm using CentOS 7 and I migrated website from php4 to php5 and I have in configuration file of Apache this between virtualhost:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
Order allow,deny
allow from all
AddDefaultCharset UTF--8

php_value session.gc_probability 1
php_value session.use_trans_sid 1
php_value PWD
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
Jun 08 09:57:55 PHABCVAPACHE systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jun 08 09:57:55 PHABCVAPACHE httpd[1401]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 24 of /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/example.com.conf:
Jun 08 09:57:55 PHABCVAPACHE httpd[1401]: php_value takes two arguments, PHP Value Modifier
Jun 08 09:57:55 PHABCVAPACHE systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 08 09:57:55 PHABCVAPACHE kill[1402]: kill: cannot find process ""
Jun 08 09:57:55 PHABCVAPACHE systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 08 09:57:55 PHABCVAPACHE systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Jun 08 09:57:55 PHABCVAPACHE systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jun 08 09:57:55 PHABCVAPACHE systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

The problem is with php_value PWD, unfortunately I don't know for what I can to change it to get apache working properly.  If I will comment it, apache is running but login form doesn't work.

Could someone to help me, please?

Comment: do not hesitate to edit and add information like your php.conf apache.con and vhost file. could you also put output of command apache2ctl configtest

Answer (score 0):

These two lines say it all:

```
Jun 08 09:57:55 PHABCVAPACHE httpd[1401]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 24 of /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/example.com.conf:
Jun 08 09:57:55 PHABCVAPACHE httpd[1401]: php_value takes two arguments, PHP Value Modifier
```

In line 24 of your example.com.conf, Apache is expecting two args for php_value. Now if the config you provided is example.com.conf, this is something you need to fix in that config file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete line

```
php_value PWD
```

because there isn't that directive in apache, and then secure your webserver in diferent way.

I don't know what you need, but you think you want to use basic auth. To do that you need to change directory section in .conf file this way:

```
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Content"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
```

and generate .htpassword file with

```
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/apache2/.htpasswd username
```